# Magento 2: How to use form key parameter in GET request?

Tags: magento2, form-validation, form-key, http-request, get

I'm using magento 2.3.4 and i tried to generate a delete cart item like this in phtml file:

```
    <?php $formKey =  $this->helper('Vendore\Module\Helper\Data')->getFormKey() ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete',array('form_key'=>$formKey,'id'=>$_item->getId())) ?>" title="<?= __("Remove Item") ?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"> <?= __("Remove Item") ?> </a>
```

the `$formKey` is retrieved successfully, but when I clicked the link it redirects me to 404 page

Comment: you need to add form key into your form not in URL.

Answer (score 0):

You will have issues trying it on M2 even though you will get the form key and print it in your get query.
Instead try to use data-post link attribute like this:

```
<a href='javascript:' data-post='{"action":"YourActionURL","data":{"id":"SomeID"}}'>Link Title</a>
```

Clicking on this link will generate a post request with a form key attached and all parameters listed in "data".